# How do I get Java to read the lowest float number

Tags: java

So I wrote this code that reads the User's lowest and highest float number. However, it reads the highest number fine, but it doesn't read the lowest number. I'm not
sure what I did wrong.

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    float cat=(float) 0.0;
    float highest = (float) 0.0;
    float lowest = (float) 0.0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (double i=0.00; i<2; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        cat = scan.nextFloat();
    if (cat > highest) {           
        highest = cat;
    }         
    else if(cat < lowest) {             
        lowest = cat;
 //I think it has something to do with the line above with lowest=cat
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

}}

Comment: There are a number of "logic errors" in your code. I think you need to learn the [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) technique for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hint: the `cat < lowest` test is OK.  The problems are in what happened before you did the test.  This is a problem that you >should< be able to solve by thinking carefully about the code you have written, and what it will do for various inputs.

Comment: See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This works, as long as you have a number greater than zero, and one less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

The test for highest and lowest are independent. You should not have an "else" joining them.

You should also consider what would happen if all the number are negative.

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize `highest` with a value lower than anything the user is likely to enter (and `lowest` with a value greater than anything the user is likely to enter). You don't use `i` other than as a loop counter, so I would make it an `int`. You don't use `cat` except as a local variable containing the current user input (so I would limit the scope to the loop body). Finally, you can use `Math.max(float, float)` and `Math.min(float, float)` to simplify your logic. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float highest = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    float lowest = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        float cat = scan.nextFloat();
        highest = Math.max(highest, cat);
        lowest = Math.min(lowest, cat);
    }
    System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always compare your input with lowest value 0.your code will only show exact output when you will take negative value input but not for positive one. here is the exact solution of your code:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
          float cat=(float) 0.0;
    float highest = (float) 0.0;
    float lowest = (float) 0.0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        cat = scan.nextFloat();
        highest=cat;
        lowest=cat;
        //assignt first input to both so it can compare with next input
    
    for (int i=0; i<(number_of_input -1); i++) {   //here i compare with (number of input -1) beacuse you have already taken a input before
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        cat = scan.nextFloat();
        if (cat > highest) {           
        highest = cat;
          //System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
    } 
    else if(cat < lowest) {             
        lowest = cat;
        //System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
      
         }
  
 
   
    }
    System.out.println("Highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Lowest number is: " + lowest);
    }
}
```